# Firebird tools gfix gbak do not launch

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Running Firebird 2.5 as a service on a local 64-bit Windows 10 machine.

isql, qli and a bunch of the other tools run just fine.

However when I try an launch gfix, gbak and gstat the window barely opens before disappearing. It does this so quickly nothing is visible.
Any recommendations for dealing with this?

My actual goal at the moment is to change a firebird database from read-only to read-write. Which you can do using gfix http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-dbmode.html

If there is some other method to change to read-write I'd happily use it.

Answer (score 2):

The tools `gfix`, `gbak` and `gstat` are command line utilities. They expect certain command line options, and they print their output to the console. If you start them by double-clicking them in explorer, or executing them from the *Run* prompt, a console is opened, output is written (the usage information as you haven't specified the necessary command line options), and then it exits, closing the console immediately.

This means that if you want to run them and see the output, you need to execute them from the command prompt (cmd), or from a batch-file that has `pause` at the end.

The fact `qli` and `isql` work by opening them from explorer (or run) is because they are interactive tools, waiting for your input.